# Apache Virtual Host not working

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I recently upgraded to the latest version of PHP (before this everything was working) and had the following virtual host configuration file under /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/local.events

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName events.local
    DocumentRoot "/home/john/development"

    <Directory "/home/john/development">
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

However instead of running my website located under /home/john/development when I go to http://local.event/ it runs the file located at /var/www/index.html.  How do I fix this and also why is this the case after I only updated PHP using the following code:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
> ServerName events.local
> ServerAleas events.local
> DocumentRoot "/home/john/development"
> ```

```
&lt;Directory "/home/john/development"&gt;
            AllowOverride All
    &lt;/Directory&gt;
&lt;/VirtualHost&gt;
 2. Need add in /etc/hosts  line (127.0.0.1    events.local)
```